# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aspose-words'

Tags: django, django-settings, aspose.words

I have installed aspose.words using the following command

```
pip install aspose-words
```

But when I add this to my installed app it showing the following error

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Core Extensions

     'aspose-words'


]

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aspose-words'
```

Comment: Is `aspose-words` a django app? It's like a regular python library in my opinion. I think you can remove it in INSTALLED_APPS.